# Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB, and video game requires an Intel HD 3000 Integrated Video Card or Better?

Tags: macos, graphics

I have an Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB on my MacBook Pro and a game I want to play is requiring an Intel HD 3000 Integrated Video Card or Better.

How can I tell if my graphics card is sufficient?